# Can't get For loop to execute more than once

Tags: javascript, loops

I have several links on my page and a function that generates the preview of each one like this:

Its supposed to loop and generate the preview for each link but it only does it one. Why is that?

```js
function parselinks() {
 var links = document.getElementsByClassName('linkprev');
 for(var link of links) {
  if(link.innerHTML =='') {
    var data = {key: 'fe2964d7c80ef2b8f6ba046ae9e8c0a5', q: link.getAttribute('href') }
    fetch('https://api.linkpreview.net', {
     method: 'POST',
     mode: 'cors',
     body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(response => {
     var linktitle = response.title;
     var linkdesc = response.description;
     var linkimg = response.image;
     link.innerHTML = `
      <span><img src="${linkimg}" alt=""></span>
      <h2>${linktitle}</h2>
      <br>
      <p>${linkdesc}</p>
     `;
    })
  }
 }
}

parselinks();
```

```css
img {width:100px;}
span {
    float: left;
}
span, h2, p {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://yahoo.com" class="linkprev"></a>
<a href="https://facebook.com" class="linkprev"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com" class="linkprev"></a>
<a href="https://instagram.com" class="linkprev"></a>
```

Comment: You probably have to change `var link` to `const link` or `let link`.

Comment: thank you, that did the trick. I would appreciate even more if you tell me why is that.